# Bootstrap 3 Navbar - Mobile Specific View

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML page that uses Bootstrap 3. In that page, I have a navbar. My navbar is slightly different. It's divided into three sections: selector, brand, and actions. On the desktop, it looks like this:

```
+------------------------+--------+------------------------+ 
| Day of Week v          | My App |    docs help welcome v |
+------------------------+--------+------------------------+
```

This is working correctly with the code below. That code is shown in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/q024Rn5srr).My challenge is, I want something kind of different on Mobile. When this page is viewed on mobile, I want it rendered as:

```
+------------------------+--------+------------------------+ 
| My App                 |        |           docs help  = |
+------------------------+--------+------------------------+
```

Then, when the user clicks the hamburger menu, I want to show the following in the hamburger menu:

```
+----------------------------+
| Day of Week v              |
|
| welcome                    |
| Your Info                  |
| Logout                     |
+----------------------------+
```

While the features are the same, the rendering is totally different. I'm not sure how to get my desired mobile view. At this point, I've tried the following ([Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/q024Rn5srr))

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0; text-align: center; margin: auto;">
        <a href="/">My App</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle banner-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Day of Week<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sunday</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">docs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle banner-username-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#" class="banner-dropdown-link">Your Info</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="banner-dropdown-link">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It's really got me puzzled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Check demo at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/YGVWBj?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="logo-center navbar-brand">
        <a href="/">My App</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-inline visible-xs navmenu-mobile" style="">
        <li><a href="#">docs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle banner-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Day of Week<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sunday</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#">docs</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle banner-username-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#" class="banner-dropdown-link">Your Info</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="banner-dropdown-link">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navmenu-mobile {
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .logo-center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not help, but it's just a thought.

Have you made sure to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This line of code to your `<head>` tag? I have found that that can hinder the expectations of mobile view on some projects I've worked on.

Comment: Yes I do have that. When I go into mobile mode, it's rendering a mobile view, its just not the correct view.

Comment: you could try using bootstraps `hidden-xs` class to make certain items appear on large vs small screens. 

In the div with your "my app" try adding the `hidden-xs` class and then make a second div utilizing `visible-xs-*` class

You could also do a same type of thing as to what is in the hamburger navigation menu on a small screen